# How to place group/order combinations into a matrix in a parameterized manner?

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix

I have an algorithm I have been trying to solve for quite some time now. I am working with the following:

- I have a "group" array that consists of six elements, and always six elements
- I have a "detail" array that consists of three to sixteen elements
- I have a "matrix" array representing a table which contains twelve columns and eight rows

My group array could look something like this (in C#):
`string[] groups = new string[] { "1_1", "1_2", "1_3", "2_1", "2_2", "2_3" };`

My detail array could look something like this (in C#):
`string[] details = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();`

I receive the number of columns and rows as a parameter, however, for all intents and purposes it is always 12 x 8, respectively. This means I have a matrix of 96 elements. I have opted to populate the matrix in a "column-major" manner, because I think it would be simpler than the alternative (but if you think this would work better in a row-major fashion, please share!). So, I have a pattern like this:

[image: 12 by 8 matrix in column-major order]

The required pattern is as follows:

[image: required pattern]

In each cell the first number represents the index of the "groups" array, while the second number represents the index of the "details" array.

Ultimately, I am looking for something like this:

[image: expected result]

I mentioned that the "details" array could have as few as 3 elements. That means my matrix would look something like this:

[image: expected result with 3 detail elements]

I do not need to "shift rows" if there are more than 8 elements but less than 16. For example, if I had 10 elements in the "details" array, my result would look like this:

[image: expected result with 10 detail elements]

I have tried various approaches to fulfill these requirements, but so far I have not been successful, including for, foreach, and while loops (sometimes nested, sometimes not), along with "mappings" of various kinds (such as using a dictionary to assist) or trying to "infer" the appropriate index from some combination of the "current column", "current row", and "current index" and operations on those figures such as division, multiplication, and the remainder. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Especially ones that are more dynamic and algorithmically simpler, but I cannot be too choosy at this point!)

I have been playing around in LINQPad, so a series of statements is great. However, I don't mind responses in other languages or even pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two expressions you're looking for are:

```
groupIndex = col / 6 * 3 + col % 3;
detailIndex = col % 6 / 3 * 8 + row;
```

where `/` represents integer division.

The group index depends only on the column number.
Dividing the column by 6 gives `0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1`
Multiply by 3 to get `0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3`
Then add the column number mod 3 to get `0 1 2 0 1 2 3 4 5 3 4 5`

The expression for the detail index is similar.
The column number mod 6 is `0  1  2  3  4  5  0  1  2  3  4  5`
Divide by 3 to get `0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1`
Then multiply by 8 to get `0  0  0  8  8  8  0  0  0  8  8  8`
Adding the row number results in the following detail indexes:

```
 0  0  0  8  8  8  0  0  0  8  8  8 
 1  1  1  9  9  9  1  1  1  9  9  9 
 2  2  2 10 10 10  2  2  2 10 10 10 
 3  3  3 11 11 11  3  3  3 11 11 11 
 4  4  4 12 12 12  4  4  4 12 12 12 
 5  5  5 13 13 13  5  5  5 13 13 13 
 6  6  6 14 14 14  6  6  6 14 14 14 
 7  7  7 15 15 15  7  7  7 15 15 15
```

Comment: Genius. Thank you for the elaboration of those expressions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. It uses Javascript.

```
//----Set up arrays.
var Groups=["1_1","1_2","1_3","2_1","2_2","2_3"];
var nGroup=Groups.length;
var Details=["1","2","3"];
var nDetail=Details.length;
var nRow=8, nCol=12, Matrix=[];
for (iRow=0; iRow<nRow; iRow++)
{ for (var iCol=0; iCol<nCol; iCol++)
  { var row=[]; for(var iCol=0; iCol<nCol; iCol++)row.push("......");
    Matrix.push(row);
  }
}

//----Set matrix values.
for (var iGroup=0; iGroup<nGroup; iGroup++)
{ for (var iDetail=0; iDetail<nDetail; iDetail++)
  { var iRow = iDetail % 8;             //----Row of matrix.
    var bigCol = parseInt(iGroup/3);    //----Major shifts by 6.
    var smallCol = parseInt(iDetail/8); //----Minor shifts by 3.
    var iCol = iGroup % 3 + (3*smallCol) + (6*bigCol); //Column of matrix.
    Matrix[iRow][iCol] = Groups[iGroup] + "(" + Details[iDetail] + ")"; //----Set val.
  }
}

Output with 9 details.
1_1(1) 1_2(1) 1_3(1) 1_1(9) 1_2(9) 1_3(9) 2_1(1) 2_2(1) 2_3(1) 2_1(9) 2_2(9) 2_3(9)
1_1(2) 1_2(2) 1_3(2) ...... ...... ...... 2_1(2) 2_2(2) 2_3(2) ...... ...... ......
1_1(3) 1_2(3) 1_3(3) ...... ...... ...... 2_1(3) 2_2(3) 2_3(3) ...... ...... ......
1_1(4) 1_2(4) 1_3(4) ...... ...... ...... 2_1(4) 2_2(4) 2_3(4) ...... ...... ......
1_1(5) 1_2(5) 1_3(5) ...... ...... ...... 2_1(5) 2_2(5) 2_3(5) ...... ...... ......
1_1(6) 1_2(6) 1_3(6) ...... ...... ...... 2_1(6) 2_2(6) 2_3(6) ...... ...... ......
1_1(7) 1_2(7) 1_3(7) ...... ...... ...... 2_1(7) 2_2(7) 2_3(7) ...... ...... ......
1_1(8) 1_2(8) 1_3(8) ...... ...... ...... 2_1(8) 2_2(8) 2_3(8) ...... ...... ......
```